# create_function instead of lambda-function avartaco

Tags: php

I was trying to implement [avartaco](https://code.google.com/p/avatarco/), which is like gravatar.

In order to make it work in php version < 5.3

> If you want to make it work on PHP less than 5.3.0, find string
>
> array_walk($shape, function(&$coord, $index, $mult) { $coord *= $mult;
> }, self::SPRITE_SIZE);
>
> and rewrite it for using create_function() instead of lambda-function.

I was getting error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION` in that same line array_walk.My php version is 5.2.17 <5.3
But I have no idea what is meant by rewriting by createfunction?

So what should I change in that line to make it work in php version < 5.3

> private function GetShape($type)    {

```
    switch($type) {

        case 'side':

            $shape_id = hexdec(substr($this->_hash, 22, 1)) & (sizeof($this->_shapesSide) - 1);

            $shapes = $this->_shapesSide;
        break;
        case 'center':
            $shape_id = hexdec(substr($this->_hash, 23, 1)) & (sizeof($this->_shapesCenter) - 1);

            $shapes = $this->_shapesCenter;
        break;

        case 'corner':
            $shape_id = hexdec(substr($this->_hash, 24, 1)) & (sizeof($this->_shapesCorner) - 1);

            $shapes = $this->_shapesCorner;
        default:
        break;

    }

    $shape = $shapes[$shape_id];
    
    array_walk($shape, function(&$coord, $index, $mult) { $coord *= $mult; }, self::SPRITE_SIZE);
    return $shape;
    
}
```

Comment: If it's not working for <5.3 then have a look [here](http://identicons.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply do the following

```
array_walk(
    $shape,
    create_function(
        '&$coord, $index, $mult',
        '$coord *= $mult;'
    ),
    self::SPRITE_SIZE
);
```

I have tested avatarico in php < 5.3 and it works!

Answer (score 7):

[Closures](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) were not introduced until PHP 5.3.

Since you are running PHP 5.2.17, you need to rewrite `array_walk()` to use `create_function()` (as the docs indicated).

```
array_walk(
  $shape,
  create_function('&$coord, $index, $mult', '$coord *= $mult'),
  self::SPRITE_SIZE
);
```

**Note:** <strike>I condensed the function as you were not using `$index`</strike>. Forgot this was a callback, so the parameters matter.

Please considering updating to *at least* PHP 5.3.

Comment: Or you can reference to a real function, which I think is a better way to go about this.

Comment: @Evert, I agree. I follow the docs suggestion. Nonetheless, I encourage you demonstrate in your own answer.

Comment: I tried the above code, and learnt about create_function, but still it dosent work. Although it does not give any error, it does not output the image.

Comment: I am not familiar with the rest of the code, but this function does not output anything. Only multiplies $coord. You may want to post more of your code as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

alternatively you can use `array_walk` callback function this way if you are below PHP 5.3

```
function array_walk_callback(&$coord, $mult){
   $coord *= $mult;
}

array_walk($shape, 'array_walk_callback', self::SPRITE_SIZE);
```

Comment: "and rewrite it for using create_function() instead of lambda-function. " what does this mean? I have posted the function GetShape where this error occurs. Please check it. I tried your code. But still no clue.